# Symfony 3 redirects to http instead of https after login

Tags: php, symfony

My whole page is in https and all links, redirects, ... work as expected. The only exception is the redirect after login.

security.yml:

```
    form_login:
        check_path: _user_login_check
        login_path: _user_login
        default_target_path: _user_dashboard_after_login
```

UserController:

```
@Route("/{_locale}/login_check", name="_user_login_check")
@Route("/{_locale}/user/logged", name="_user_dashboard_after_login")
```

So why is the redirect after login to _user_dashboard_after_login using http? The Server then redirects again to the https destination, which in turn works as expected.

Comment: Do you use redirect input field in your login form?

Comment: No. The form consists of email, password and submit.

Comment: Personally I would look at routing.yml files, if there are some protocol limitations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More that 2 years old question but i hope to help anyone who runs into this issue.

While the redirection that Symfony perform during login, it decides whether to redirect to http or https depending on some checks on http headers and proxy whitelist. This is done in: isSecure() method in Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request.php.
Check [this documentation topic](https://symfony.com/doc/current/deployment/proxies.html).